# Google Analytics numbers start out high at the beginning of the day and later drop

Tags: google-analytics

My Google Analytics numbers change downward randomly. Where once a particular page/post or even day will show 4000 visits, when I go back later in the day, the same variable is reduced to 1500 or something.

Even my total numbers change downward. I'll look at the total page views for the month in the morning and then in again in afternoon and the second time they will always show several thousand fewer.

What's going on?

Comment: I have the same issue, but with the opposite effect. It shows me 1500 visits, the next day 4000 visits and the next day are reduced to back 1500. Comparing Google Analytics with other counters, I am sure that the correct number is 1500. I believe that it is a bug.

Comment: Lotusms - it's not about the numbers going up and down across a day or month it's about the same variable showing reduced numbers. For example, this morning the rolling month page views showed 73K +, later today, same variable, same parameters showed 68K - why the decline of total views. Happens with page views too. A particular story will show 4000 hits on let's say 3/10 when first viewed. If I pull up 3/10 a second time, it may show 3000 hits. The numbers on any given day seem to change downward, across the day. The numbers had already been counted, why would they move down, once in?

Comment: Currently noticing the same kind of issues, I'm not a pro user of analytics but intrigued why Wednesday visits showed massive jump to 11K+ (from 5K prev. day), then today (Friday) Wed. now (genuine?) 5.5K and yesterday (Thurs) 10.5K+

Answer (score 1):

You probably where having issues with **ghost referrals** or with third party websites crawlers also known as **bots**. It is claimed that ghost referrals are a serious problem and will mess up with your data. On the contrary, some legitimately bots will periodically visit your website to extract data from you to feed or update their records about you.

You should identify if you are having issues with referrals or if there is a recurring visit to your site from any particular bot within the affected time frame.

Searching in google for ghost referrals will yield many possible solutions or how to fix it. For those bots that you can identify you should decide either to block them via robots.txt or create filtered view in GA. However, be careful not to block "good" bots from services that you are running and that might require to visit your website now and then.

Answer (score 0):

One of my analytics properties has the same issue.   It appears to be a double counting issue.   The numbers start out impossibly high and are revised downward later in the day.

The later numbers are always the ones that stick.  It never goes back to the previously reported figures.   For me the high figures are often about double what I would expect them to be and get taken down by about half.

Since March when you asked this question, the situation has improved for my property.  I haven't noticed this phenomenon in a while.   It sees to me like it was likely a bug that the Google Analytics team has fixed.